# How to add a target_blank to a registration button

Tags: html, target

How do I make this registration button open in a new page?

```
$register_button = '<a id="a_register_link-'.$event->id.'" href="'.get_option('siteurl').'/?page_id='.$event_page_id.'&regevent_action=register&event_id='.$event->id.'&name_of_event='.stripslashes_deep($event->event_name).'">Register</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a target="_blank" ... >Register</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to add a `target="_blank"` inside the anchors.

```
$register_button = '<a id="a_register_link-'.$event->id.'" href="'.get_option('siteurl').'/?page_id='.$event_page_id.'&regevent_action=register&event_id='.$event->id.'&name_of_event='.stripslashes_deep($event->event_name).'" target="_blank">Register</a>';
```